# Spring Data Jpa saveAndFlush method not commit session immediately

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a service method saving a new  entity ,and I need the auto-generated id so that I can go on subsequent logic, so I use the saveAndFlush() method. but something the id is no generated before following code

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void method1() {

        User user = new User();
        User savedUser = userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

        // according to the logs on event listener, the id of savedUser is sometimes null
        eventPublisher.publish(savedUser);
    }
```

why the saveAndFlush not save to DB and generated id before it send out the event ?

Comment: flushing isn't the same as committing!. flushing only issues the pending sql statements to the db in the current transaction so that from within the tx it has a known and valid state. You can still rollback.

Answer (score 0):

eventPublisher.publish(savedUser);

This line of code is in transaction ==> @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)

do one thing 
eventPublisher.publish(savedUser); run this in separate thread

Use Below code:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void method1() {
        ExecutorService executor = null;
        try {
            User user = new User();
            User savedUser = userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                // according to the logs on event listener, the id of savedUser is sometimes
                // null
                eventPublisher.publish(savedUser);
            }, executor);
        } finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't, as that will also publish a message in case of a rollback (for whatever reason).

Comment: @M.Deinum then how to avoid publish in case of rollback, could u give some code examples. and I want the new id always have value when publish

Comment: Use a transactional event listener.